# Getting multiple Django application site to resolve by port numbers

Tags: django, apache

I have a Django website where I run multiple sites.  Each application has a seperate apache instance and port assigned to it.  the host.py file looks like the following

```
host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'.*domain1.*', 'domain1.urls', name='domain1'),
    host(r'.*domain2.*', 'domain2.urls', name='domain2'),
    host(r'.*domain3.*', 'domain3.urls', name='domain3'),
    host(r'.*domain4.*', 'domain4.urls', name='domain4'),
    host(r'.*domain5.*', 'domain5.urls', name='domain5'),

)
```

for example www.domain1.com runs under an apache instance and port 8010.
Id like to create some internal monitors so I can check each site on a specific server.  The only way to do this is with using port numbers of the apache instance so as http://10.10.10.10:8010 but when i try to modify my site to do this I get application errors.

either by adding a line for domain

```
host(r'.*8010.*', 'domain1.urls', name='domain1'),
```

or modifying existing line

```
host(r'.*domain1.*|.*8010.*', 'domain1.urls', name='domain1'),
```

not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the second option,  i must have had a typo or something initially.